# Is it possible to create salty ice cream?

Tags: ice-cream

I have heard that in Japan people eat some kind of salty ice cream. Is it true? If it is true, does anyone know the name of the dish or how to prepare it?

Comment: Maybe I'm just missing something...have you tried adding salt?

Comment: If you're asking for a recipe for salty ice cream, that's off-topic for the site. Are you searching for the name of a particular variety of ice cream?

Comment: It's possible to create pretty much any type of ice-cream; I've had sea salt ice-cream before and it works surprisingly well.

Comment: If they can do Bacon Ice Cream [and they do...](http://bacontoday.com/uses-for-bacon/bacon-ice-cream/) they can do salty ice cream.

Comment: Not quite an answer, but related: we've recently made vanilla ice cream, and added some *fresh green curry* to it (using an ice cream machine) which was very strange but not all too bad. There was some salt in the curry as well, though not enough to make the ice cream taste "salty".

Comment: Apparently, in Regency England, things like Parmesan ice cream were all the rage.

Comment: I had dill pickle gelato in Italy.  Frankly, I thought it was awful, but it shows you can flavor ice cream with pretty much anything.

Comment: Salt is an ingredient in most ice creams, and there are a variety of particularly salty ice creams. For instance, bacon ice cream is occasionally accompanied by coarse sea or rock salt. Specifically noted from Japan though [Sea Salt ice cream](http://www.geekychef.com/2009/01/sea-salt-ice-cream.html) is also a popular creation, consisting of a sea salt and vanilla flavoring in blue colored ice cream, allegedly made famous after Tetsuya Nomura of Square Enix fame tried it at a Tokyo Disney resort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Sea Salt ice cream" is the one I've heard about. It's literally flavored by sea salt. Online recipes are often themed around the game series Kingdom Hearts, in which a main character enjoys this treat. That ought to be enough to help your search :)

Answer (score 0):

I've made miso caramel ice cream, salted caramel ice cream is a popular flavor in the Seattle area, and an uncle of mine tried an olive-oil and salt gelato at one of Mario Batali's restaurants, and I've had a salted peanut butter ice cream at a restaurant a few years back. There wasn't much adjustment required to accommodate the salt; unless you're using so much as to be unpalatable, it won't dramatically change freezing temperature or texture. If you're using less sugar, that can be a factor, but there are other coping strategies for that (alcohol, etc).